# Button disappears in 3.5 inch format (Xcode).

Tags: iphone, ios

In the `.xib file` in Xcode I have a button in my App at the bottom of a view.

I build the interface in the 4 inch size of the iPhone 5, but if I place a button at the bottom of the view, I see the button no longer in the iPhone Simulator 3.5 inch.
How can I ensure that the button is also just down the 3.5 inch format and that the button does not disappear?.

Comment: use auto sizing bottom margin and left margin on rest of all are off for this particular button

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XIB or Storyboard to create your UIButton, go to your button's size inspector.
You can set the Autosizing bottom margin from here.

[image: Autosizing mask]

You can also do it programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, but i can find "AutoSizing bottom margin" in the button size inspector?

Comment: OK, I added a screenshot. By selecting the "bottom margin" from here, you can tell the button to stick to it's bottom position when its superview frame changes.

Comment: I can't see that, I'm using .xib but if I go to the size inspector nowhere I see "autosizing" . Can you make a bigger screenshot please?

Comment: I alreadt found the solution: under the file inspector check "Use Autolayout"

Comment: OK, great. The only drawbacks with Autolayout is that they are only available on iOS 6. But that does the trick too!